# How to get the cell reference from a gesture of another item in the cell

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` which has some custom cells. Within the custom cells I have a main `UIImageView`. When the cell is created I add a Tap Gesture Recogniser to the image view.

When the image is tapped I run the following:

```
- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"Image tapped");
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    // send the image instead of self when firing the segue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"remindMeTurnInfo" sender:imageView];
}
```

I then pass the image into a new view controller in `prepareForSegue` method:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"remindMeTurnInfo"]) {
        UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)sender;
        MESPlayedTurnReminderViewController *VC = segue.destinationViewController;
        VC.turnImage = imgView.image;
    }
```

**Question** 
1. I need a reference to the cell that the UIImageView is within, that was tapped. So the user taps one of the cells images, and I need to know which cell (indexPath) that image was tapped from. 
2. I am finding that sometimes when the image is tapped the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is being called. This is incorrect and it should not be called, only the relevant handleTap method from the Gesture Rec. should be called. How can I ensure that the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called, as I need to run some other code when the cell is actually (correctly) selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways this is commonly done. Either add a tag to your image view in cellForRowAtIndexPath that's equal to indexPath.row, or search up through the hierarchy of views from the image view until you find one that's a UITableViewCell (or subclass). That can be done like this:

```
- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    UIView *superview = imageView.superview;
    while (![superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
        superview = superview.superview;
    }
    NSLog(@"indexPath.row is: %d", [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)superview].row);
}
```

The reason to search rather than using something like imageView.superview.superview (which would work in iOS 6), is that the hierarchy can change in different versions of iOS, and in fact, it did change between iOS 6 and iOS 7.

As for your second question, it probably happens because you're accidentally tapping the cell rather than the image view. Other than making the image view larger so it's easier to tap, I don't see a fix for that.

Comment: Thanks for this approach. This is great, but how would I then look to pass the indexPath into the prepareForSegue method. At present I pass in the imageView as the sender for the method, so that I can link to the image (per the question) but how would I pass the indexPath in as I actually need this in the prepareForSegue method instead.

Comment: I was able to replicate the above in the prepareForSegue method without any issues which is great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1.- To get the cell you can check the superview of the UIImageView tapped

```
- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{    
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)imageView.superview;
}
```

2.- To disable the cell selection on a UITableView

```
[self.yourTableView setAllowsSelection:NO];
```